# Express each of the following in modulus-argument form, where theta is between zero and pi over 2.

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

> (a) Express each of the following in modulus-argument form, where $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$:
> $$\text{i)}\ 1+i\tan\theta,\quad\text{ii)}\ 1+i\cot\theta,\quad\text{iii)}\ \frac{1}{\sin\theta}+\frac{1}{\cos\theta}i.$$
> (b) Hence simplify each of the following:
> $$\text{i)}\ (1+i\tan\theta)^2,\quad\text{ii)}\ (1+i\cot\theta)^{-3},\quad\text{iii)}\ \frac{1}{\sin\theta}-\frac{1}{\cos\theta}i.$$

I can answer all the questions in my math textbook except for this question. And there are no specific examples of this question in my textbook. Any help is appreciated.
THANKS

Comment: Well, you can start by calculating the modulus for each of the three cases in part (a). It's easy because it's just the square root of the sum of the real part squared plus imaginary part squared. So you don't really need to calculate anything, only write down the expressions. Can you do that?

Comment: @Matti P I know how to find the modulus but not the argument.

Comment: The argument of a complex number is the angle that it makes with the real axis. So if you have a complex number of the form $a+bi$, the angle $\theta$ fulfills
$$
\tan \theta = \frac{b}{a}
$$
Usually we need to solve for $\theta$. If we start with the first one, it's pretty easy to read the coordinates $a$ and $b$. The real part is always exactly $1$, and the imaginary part is defined as $\tan \theta$. What can you conclude? It's also useful to draw a picture of the possible "locations" of this complex numbers in the complex plane. In this case, it's a straight line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your examples are of the form
$$a(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$$
For example,
$$1+i\tan\theta=\frac{1}{\cos\theta}(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$$
Can you do the rest? Please tell me if you need any more help.

Note that as $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ the values of both $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ will always be positive.